# calling one constructor from another in same class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, compiler-errors

1) First Code

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
    int b;
    A(int temp){
        i=temp;
        A();
        b=0;
    }

    A(){
        b=0;
    }

    void display(){
        printf("%d %d\n",i,b);//1 0
    }
};

int  main(){
    A Aobj(1);
    Aobj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 1 0

2) Second Code

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
    int b;
    A(int temp) : i(temp), A(), b(0) {}//Error
    A() : b(0) {}
    void display(){
        printf("%d %d\n",b,i);
    }
};

int  main()
{
    A Aobj(1);
    Aobj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting that both the codes will show same behavior and will produce an error as calling one constructor from the other in the same class is not permitted. **It's not C++11.**

So why does using the intializer list make a difference? 
I compiled this codes in g++ 4.3.4 .

Comment: C++11 allows for delegating constructors like in your second example, not calling them inside the body. It sounded like you were expecting an error from the first for that reason, so I wanted to make sure that was clear.

Comment: second Chris here, you should read about C++ Delegating Constructors.
Reference: http://www.nullptr.me/2012/01/17/c11-delegating-constructors

Answer (score 2):

`A();` is not doing what you think it does.

Replace it with `double();` or `char();` or any other type.  Note that it works.

All you are doing is creating an anonymous additional instance of the type then throwing it away.  It has no impact on `this` and will not do what you think it does.

The initializer list works in C++11 the way you would expect.

Comment: Please Explain a bit more.What should I replace.and than why it works for the replacement.I know I am breaking the rules but why the rules are not same for both the cases, as both should be erroneous.

Comment: There is exactly one spot in your code that you have the characters `A();` right?  That is not doing what you think it is doing.  It is creating an unrelated temporary of type A then discarding it.

Comment: What does this statement do: `int();`?  How about this function: `void foo (){ A(); }`?  How about this function `void bar() { A a = A(); }`?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with C++11 at all.

As pointed out by Yakk in the first case, you construct an anonymous member non recursively through a different constructor (the default constructor).

In case 'B'; you try to initialize from the initialzier list a member that doesn't exist. You don't have an instance of `A` or an `A*` existing within `A` to initialize.